# How can I serialize a Lookup

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm working on a project for work where I need to binary serialize every object returned by one of our `ProxyFactories`.
We decided it would be fine to require a `Serializable` attribute on every class to be returned but my problem now is that I can't serialize the `LookUp` object that *.NET* provides.

Is there anyway that I can work around this without changing this to be a `Dictionary`?

My only other idea is to create my own class to implement ILookup but surely there must be an easier way.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the class in question.

Comment: Have you tried a serializer that doesn't require attributes? Such as Json.NET or ServiceStack or protobuf-net?

Comment: I wanted to use the default binary serializer in hopes that it would give me the closest representation of how my object is actually being stored in memory. I'm trying to measure the approximate size of our objects in our cache.
I'm not against using any of those 3, I just wanted to explore this option first

Comment: You're falling victim to the XY Problem here.  If you want to measure the memory space of .Net objects, consider starting with Process Explorer or a dedicated memory profiling tool.

Comment: The problem with using either of those solutions is that I want this to be done during every cache miss (well during a sample of cache misses) programatically so I can ship these statistics to another server where we compare cache miss times vs cache miss % vs cache size.

We are totally fine with this not being completely right, I already know that binary serialization won't give the perfect answer. But I can use this to get an idea of which cached objects are the biggest

Comment: Please post how you are using LookUp.